# Como utilizar um único arquivo de variáveis globais utilizando CSS Modules e CSS Inline?

Tags: javascript, css, react, react-hooks, sass

Estou iniciando um projeto React.js com SCSS e tentando desenvolver uma biblioteca de componentes UI própria. Para padronizar os estilos eu utilizaria um arquivo tema (com as variáveis globais). Minha dúvida é sobre como usar esse tema tanto nos arquivos SCSS quanto nos componentes React através do CSS inline, vou ter que criar dois arquivos com os mesmos valores porém um Javascript e outro SCSS?

O objetivo seria utilizar nos meus componentes reutilizáveis o CSS modules e passar uma props style,por exemplo, modificando o estilo de acordo com o momento específico, assim sendo aplicado o CSS inline.

Aqui declaro o meu componente, estilizo ele com CSS Modules e passo as propriedades via props:

```
import styles from "./stackStyles.module.scss";

export default function Stack({
 children,
 justifyContent,
 direction,
 alignItems,
 style,
 ref,
}) {
return (
 <>
  <div
    ref={ref}
    className={`${styles.flex}`}
    style={{ justifyContent, alignItems, direction, ...style }}
  >
  {children}
  </div>
</>
);
}
```

Chamo o meu componente e estilizo ele de acordo com a necessidade atual através da props style:

```
<Stack
  justifyContent="center"
  alignItems="center"
  style={{ height: "100px" }}
>
  <Stack
    Ref={stackRef}
    style={{
      borderRadius: "50%",
      backgroundColor: "grey",
      cursor: "pointer",
    }}
  >
    <Icon />
  </Stack>
</Stack>
```

A solução criando dois temas teria um arquivo scss desta forma:

```
$font-size-small: 12px;
$font-size-medium: 16px;
$font-size-large: 24px;
$font-size-xlarge: 36px;

$color-primary: #1a1b41;
$color-secondary: #aeb8fe;
$color-success: #a9ffcb;
$color-danger: #f22b29;
$color-warning: #ffc53a;
$color-info: #17a2b8;
$color-light: #f8f9fa;
$color-dark: #343a40;
$color-white: #fff;
```

E outro javascript desta forma:

```
    const theme = {
    fontSize: {
      xsmall: '10px',
      small: '12px',
      medium: '16px',
      large: '24px',
      xlarge: '36px'
    },
    color: {
      primary: '#1a1b41',
      secondary: '#aeb8fe',
      success: '#a9ffcb',
      danger: '#f22b29',
      warning: '#ffc53a',
      info: '#17a2b8',
      light: '#f8f9fa',
      dark: '#343a40',
      white: '#fff'
     },
    };
    export default theme;
```

Isso não me parece uma boa prática por ser necessário alterar dois arquivos pra alterar qualquer propriedade. Alguma outra solução?

Comment: Importante [editar sua postagem original](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/580768/70) detalhando melhor e aguardar o processo de reavaliação em vez de duplicar o assunto. Para entender melhor o objetivo do site, uma lida na [help] e respectivos links pode ajudar. Em tese deve ser possível você junto da edição fornecer um [mcve] do problema. Para evitar duplicação de informações o espaço de comentários foi desativado aqui, mas pode ser usado na postagem original.